# select string line until specified row of string line vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to read from selected line index until selected row of line. But It's always start on the first line and not from selected line. Selected row is define from selected datagrid row. Appreciate any help

```
    Dim intIdx As Integer = 0 'File Index
    Dim intDataSetCount As Integer = 0
    Dim intSelRow As Integer = 127 'selected row line
    Dim file As String = "file"
    Dim line As String = ""
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file)

    For Each line In lines
        intDataSetCount = intDataSetCount + 1
        If intSelRow < intDataSetCount Then
            intIdx = intIdx + 1
        End If
        TextBox1.AppendText(line & vbNewLine)
        If intDataSetCount = 156 Then 'until selected row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually need the contents of the file in an array then you can use the [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method with a bit of LINQ to get just the lines you want:

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, File.ReadLines(sourceFile).Skip(firstLine - 1).Take(lastLine - firstLine + 1))
```

where `firstLine` is the number of the first line you want, counting the first line in the file as 1, and `sourceFile` is the full path to the file you want the lines from.

Using `File.ReadLines` has the advantage that it will only read as much as required, so if you only wanted a few lines from a large file then it would not be wasting memory storing the rest of the file.

---

If you don't want to use the above method, you could do something like:

```
Sub ShowLines3(sourceFile As String, firstLine As Long, lastLine As Long)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Using sr As New StreamReader(sourceFile)
        If Not sr.EndOfStream Then
            For i = 1 To lastLine
                If i >= firstLine Then
                    sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine())
                Else
                    sr.ReadLine()
                End If

                If sr.EndOfStream Then
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next

        End If

    End Using

    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString()

End Sub
```

The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) construct takes care of cleaning up after using the StreamReader.

Checking for `sr.EndOfStream` avoids any unnecessary attempts to read from the file when the end has been reached already (e.g. you could set `lastLine` to `Long.MaxValue` to read to the end of the file).

Using a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7) is an efficient way of constructing a large string from many pieces

Comment: IMO, Linq is almost always the way to go with these sorts of things. Chances are pretty low that we're going to write a more efficient algorithm for these sorts of operations.

Comment: Hi Mike, I think you're right. Because I need to read thousands of lines per file. I run your code and awesome speed. Thanks a lot.